# pointwise convergence implies $L^p$ convergence in this case?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ pointwise and $\int_0^T f(t)$ is finite, does $f_n$ converge to $f$ in $L^p$ for any $p$? I think so, because $f_n$ converges so it's bounded, so one can use DCT. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because $f_n$ converges so it's bounded

This means that for all $x$, the sequence $(f_n(x),n\geqslant 1)$ is bounded by a $M_x$. But this doesn't prove that the function $x\mapsto M_x$ is integrable, assumption needed in the dominated convergence theorem.

Actually, under the assumptions in the OP, we don't have necessarily convergence in $L^1$, as the example $f_n:=n\chi_{(0,n^{-1})}$ shows.

Comment: .thanks so much

Comment: You are welcome.